# How to add the column headers on every page on python-docx?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I'm trying to print a Pandas data frame as .docx file on python. My problem is since the docx file will most of the time print more than 1 page, I want to have the column names of the data frame to be printed for every new page.

Currently my code just prints the whole data frame as is:

```
# add the header rows.
for j in range(t01.shape[-1]):
 table.cell(0,j).text = t01.columns[j]
        
# add the rest of the data frame
for i in range(t01.shape[0]):
 for j in range(t01.shape[-1]):
  table.cell(i+1,j).text = str(t01.values[i,j])
```

Comment: hey does the answer provided below answer your question? if not is there something I can add to make it so?

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. I'm just trying out the solution now since I was on a long vacation. I'll get back to you if ever I have some questions. thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you're probably looking after is `Repeat Header Rows` functionality which can be find in here:
[image: ms word screenshot on how to make table row a header row]

since `python-docx` doesn't have that functionality yet, you can add that flag by yourself. first you need to look for it in the ooxml schema http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/e-w_tblHeader-1.html

note that rows that are declared as header rows will repeat themselves at the beginning of every page if the table can't fit onto a single page. so what you need to do is to declare the first row as a header row. that can be done like:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement

doc = Document()
t = doc.add_table(rows=50, cols=2)

# set header values
t.cell(0, 0).text = 'A'
t.cell(0, 1).text = 'B'

tbl_header = OxmlElement('w:tblHeader') # create new oxml element flag which indicates that row is header row
first_row_props = t.rows[0]._element.get_or_add_trPr() # get if exists or create new table row properties el
first_row_props.append(tbl_header) # now first row is the header row

for i in range(1, len(t.rows)):
    for j in range(len(t.columns)):
        t.cell(i, j).text = f'i:{i}, j:{j}'

doc.save('t1.docx')
```

the end result should look like:

[image: generated ms word document with repeating header]

Comment: Thanks for this solution aleksandarbos. Worked for me straight away. 

And the link to OOXML schema is good to know about too, as may find more things not supported by Python-Docx yet.